# Python negative subscripting

Tags: python, indices, subscript

I'm currently reading Robert Sebesta's Concepts of Programming Languages, 10th edition (2012). In the chapter about data types, it reads "Ruby and Lua support negative subscripts, but Python does not". I thought negatives subscripts could be done in Python using `list_name[-i]`. What are negative subscripts then?

Comment: Strange. I can see how terminology misuse might lead to the Lua claim, but Ruby [appears to behave](http://codepad.org/DFouLDxR) exactly like Python in this regard.

Comment: You count from the back, i.e. `list[-1]` is the last element of a list, `list[-2]` is the next to last element and so on.

Comment: The author may be wrong? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Strings

Comment: @zhangxaochen That's what I thought, but it's still pretty weird to get something like that wrong.

Comment: @FelipeCortez maybe you could contact the author for more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python, Lua, and Ruby support negative subscripts. In Python, this feature was added as [a footnote in version 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node10.html#SECTION003150000000000000000) and [reaffirmed as extended slicing in version 2.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html)

On p.264 of Sebesta's book (10th ed.) he claims Python does not support negative indexing on arrays. The original text was overhauled and republished as edition 6 in 2004, while Python 2.3 was released on July 29, 2003. I'm guessing extended slicing was overlooked and been in error since the release of Sebesta's 6th edition.

I cannot find errata for the 10th edition. You may want to email the author and inform him.

Comment: The ability to use negative indexes has been in Python since at least Version 1.4. Extended slicing simply extended slicing to tuples, lists and strings - negative indexing was already available. Sometimes textbooks are wrong.

Comment: I thought that may be the case, but I couldn't find any evidence about the features pre 1.5. At any rate, the author seems unaware of the error so it would be worthwhile to contact him.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node10.html#SECTION003150000000000000000 footnote 1 shows that even in 1.5 negative indexes were a standard feature of the language.

Answer (score 2):

In Python and Ruby, a negative subscript indexes backward from the end of the array. That is, when the subscript is negative, the array length is added to it.

This is not the case in Lua. A negative subscript has no special meaning; it simply references or creates a table entry with that negative number as the key.

Python 2.7.3:

```
>>> a = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
>>> a
['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> a[-1]
'z'
>>> a[-1] = 'm'
>>> a
['x', 'y', 'm']
>>>
```

Ruby 1.9.3:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
=> ["x", "y", "z"]
irb(main):002:0> a
=> ["x", "y", "z"]
irb(main):003:0> a[-1]
=> "z"
irb(main):004:0> a[-1] = 'm'
=> "m"
irb(main):005:0> a
=> ["x", "y", "m"]
irb(main):006:0>
```

Lua 5.2.3:

```
> a = { 'x', 'y', 'z' }
> for key, value in pairs(a) do print( key, value ) end
1       x
2       y
3       z
> print( a[3] )
z
> print( a[-1] )
nil
> a[-1] = 'm'
> print( a[-1] )
m
> for key, value in pairs(a) do print( key, value ) end
1       x
2       y
3       z
-1      m
>
```

JavaScript's behavior is fairly similar to Lua's. You can use a negative subscript on an array, and in fact you can use any arbitrary *string* as a subscript. A JavaScript array is actually an object with some additional methods, properties (`.length`) and behavior (updating `.length` as needed). When you use `array[-1]` you're adding or referencing a property with the key `"-1"`, and `.length` is not updated.

Chrome 33:

```
> var a = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
undefined
> a
["x", "y", "z"]
> a[2]
"z"
> a[-1]
undefined
> a[-1] = 'm'
"m"
> a[-1]
"m"
> a[2]
"z"
> a
["x", "y", "z"]
> for( var key in a ) console.log( key, a[key] );
0 x
1 y
2 z
-1 m
undefined
```

Don't be misled by the `undefined` printed at the end - that's not part of the  `for( var key in a )` enumeration, it's just printed there because `console.log()` is the last expression evaluated in the loop and it does not return a value (it just *prints* a value).

Comment: I've already considered that, but it's not kosher either, because the Python and Ruby equivalent of a Lua table isn't an list/array but a dict/hash. Those do, of course, also support any indices.

Comment: Lua's behavior is similar to JavaScript's, right? It's like the indices were dictionary keys.

Comment: @delnan - Yes, that is a good point. A Lua table can be *used* as an array, and Lua has some optimizations to support this case, but in principle it is more like a dict or hash.

Comment: @FelipeCortez - That sounds right to me. I added a JavaScript test to compare.